# Does PrintWriter have some kind of internal buffer?

Tags: android, xamarin

Im having some trouble sending more than 1024 bytes through PrintWriter.  Here's my code

```
                        String asB64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(jdata);
                        JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
                        j.Put("type", "image");
                        j.Put("data", asB64);
                        string msg = j.ToString();
                        writer.Print(msg);

                        writer.Print('\r');
                        writer.Print('\n');
                        writer.Flush();
                        break;
```

if I send less than 1024 bytes, all is well.  Anything over that limit doesnt work. Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean that it doesn't work? Is there an exception, it fails to output, it fails to output part of the content?

Comment: That looks like C#; are you sure this is Java?

Comment: Its actually Xamarin (for android, so essentially its Java).  What happens is it proceeds on, but the server never gets the data unless it is less that 1024 bytes.  Maybe some kind of socket buffer size limit?

Answer (score 1):

Disregard.  It's completely the server's fault. Mods can delete this one.